# Android Studio Error when i run the app

Tags: android

```
    05-19 19:01:12.956 31642-31649/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A 
   SQLiteConnection object for database 
 '+data+user+0+com_google_android_gms+databases+metrics_db' was leaked!  Pe fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

This is what i get in android monitor after i run the app and crush before to create main activity.

I don't know what to do...

Please help

Comment: The log above is very hard to read. Could you only post the error lines and also make them wrapped in code? That way other users would be able to help you faster.

Answer (score 0):

When you are finished with the database and close the app or activity, you have to call:

```
db.close();
```

where db is your database instance. You cause a memory leak by not calling .close on the database.

Comment: Your stacktrace says otherwise: `SQLiteConnection object for database `